# Unable to install Android studio on Windows

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I am trying to install android studio on windows but I cannnot run the intstallation file. I downloaded the installion file from Android studios website but in my downloads they just appear as .dll files which I cannot execute like in the attached picture. I have installed Android studio on my laptop without issue so I feel there is something missing on my Desktop.
Wondering if anyone can advise?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you downloaded it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio?gclsrc=aw.ds&gclid=Cj0KCQjw7pKFBhDUARIsAFUoMDYM4JfzGaHCtL_eAnjppQ8yhBvB4PCYQq8QHye1zHx5DRcW5OayYU8aAq00EALw_wcB)?

Comment: Correct I downloaded it from there

Comment: I downloaded it right now without problem. Try renaming file removing dll extension

Comment: Removing .dll worked thanks for your help

Comment: That's...really strange, what browser are you using that's adding a .dll extension?

Comment: @RyanM it was firefox